# Nagios won't run when I add this

Tags: http, webserver, ping, nagios

I want to be able to check if my site is up and monitor it by nagios locally.

So I went to this site http://www.linickx.com/nagios which made the following, now while I cant see hosts.cfg so I created it and also services.cfg I had to create as well:

```
hosts.cfg
    #  host definition for bonus
    define host{
    use                     generic-host            ; Name of host template to use
    host_name               bonus
    alias                   bonus
    address                 92.12.35.162
    check_command           check-host-alive
    max_check_attempts      10
    notification_interval   120
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_options    d,u,r}  
    services config

The following should appended to the end of hosts.cfg (located in /etc/nagios or /usr/local/nagios/etc)
# Service definition for bonus
define service{
use             generic-service     ; Name of service template to use
host_name           bonus
service_description     HTTP
is_volatile         0
check_period            24x7
max_check_attempts      3
normal_check_interval       3
retry_check_interval        1
contact_groups          technical,support
notification_interval       120
notification_period     24x7
notification_options        w,u,c,r
check_command           check_http
}
```

How can I get this to work please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios won't add new configuration files unless either the file or directory is specified in the main nagios.cfg. Also, the new object configurations won't be added until you restart the Nagios process. Can you give some more detail as to how you installed Nagios (source or package) and what linux distro you're on?

Here are some additional resources:

Nagios Core Documentation
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/

Nagios Core Support Forum
http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=7

Comment: installed it by yum install nagios